# Align origins to bottom of objects

Tags: modeling, mesh, origin

Is there a way to align origins of multiple objects to their lowest point without addons, custom scripts?
I want to modify only Z coordinate, the others leave intact. For example there are furnitures with origins at their bounding box center, and the modify them so, that they stand on their legs if I set their Z to 0.

There are a lot of objects, I'd like to place the origins to their bottom. Here is a very simplified example:

[image]

Now the origins are at center of mass, they need to be on the bottom:

[image]

I have a lot of objects, manual techniques are not suitable here. This is a very common task, I need it every day. Hard to believe, Blender has no function for this.

Comment: How do you already know Blender can't do that? Align tools addon can do that. In N panel click Advanced, Pivot mode, include active object by *Active too*, Self mode, Min option to align to minimum of each alignment for each object (so, minimum position for Z axis), pick Z axis. See also https://blenderartists.org/t/multiple-objects-origin-to-base/1295029

Comment: Well…he wrote: without add-on. Although I don’t understand that restriction…it's a bit like "i wanna drive my car without using fuel..." (and it's hard to believe my car cannot do that) :D

Comment: Align tool does it. This is the best method.

My "without addon" restriction applies to external addons, especially paid ones. I don't want to buy an addon for every basic task. Align tools is not too user-friendly compared to some addons on Blendermarket, but at least it is built in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Python script

Select the objects, run Python script:

```py
import bpy
from bpy import context as C

for z, co in [(o.bound_box[0][2], v.co) for o in C.selected_objects for v in o.data.vertices]:
    co.z -= z
```

Comment: Although I wrote "without scripting", this solution really works well.

Comment: @Denatural D'oh! It's time for me to learn how to read again...

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the lowest vertex of the model in *edit mode*
2. Then press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and pick *Cursor to Selected*
3. Leave *edit mode* and select from menu: *Object>Set origin>Origin to 3D cursor.*

Comment: for multiple objects? who wants to do that?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what I need.